# Unity3D SetDestination Update

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my test, I found that navMeshAgent.SetDestination works when it is placed in Update function, but in other function it doesn't work. I wonder how it happens and beg for your answers.

Soldier.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Soldier : MonoBehaviour {
    private UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;

    void Awake() {
    }

    void Start() {
        navMeshAgent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update() {
    }

    public void DispatchTroops(Vector3 destination) {
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(destination);
    }
}
```

AddSoldiers.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AddSoldiers : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject soldier;
    static readonly int soldiersNumber = 10;

    private Vector3 src;
    bool order = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        Button btw = this.GetComponent<Button>();
        btw.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        src = Vector3.zero;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (order) {
            StartCoroutine(GenerateSoliders(new Vector3(5f, 5f, 5f)));
            order = false;
        }
    }

    // Click button
    public void TaskOnClick() {
        order = true;
    }

    // Add a few soldiers
    IEnumerator GenerateSoliders(Vector3 destination) {
        for (int i = 0; i < soldiersNumber; i++) {
            GameObject s = Instantiate(soldier, src, Quaternion.identity);
            s.GetComponent<Soldier>().DispatchTroops(destination);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is as above. In commander gameObjcet, firstly I create a soldier gameObject, then I call soldier's member function DispatchTroops. But an error occured:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Soldier.DispatchTroops(Vector3 destination) (at Assets/Scenes/Soldier.cs:19).
```

If I put navMeshAgent.SetDestination in Update function, it works.

Comment: Please add screenshot or any messages to precise your question.

Comment: @Programmer I feel guilty to post my question in a hurry. Now I revise my question and post my solution as below. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the function call order is :

Awake() > user-defined member function > Start() > Update()

thus when I call DispatchTroops function, soldier's Start() function hasn't been called so navMeshAgent is not initialized, then I get NullReferenceException error.

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you have posted, you are not calling the function, you are just defining the function. And in the description, you said you are calling the function. Where did you try calling the function?
If you are defining a function you should call it in Update(), Start() or Awake().
Remeber when you are calling the function you will have to call new on the Vector3 in the parameter.

```
DispatchTroops(new Vector3 (x,y,z));
```

Comment: I revise my question and post another code as above. In commander gameObjcet, firstly I create a soldier gameObject, then I call soldier's member function DispatchTroops. I found that the function call order is : Awake() > user-defined member function > Start() > Update(), thus when I call DispatchTroops function, soldier's Start() function hasn't been called so navMeshAgent is not initialized, then I get NullReferenceException error. Anyway, thanks a lot.